# How to exclude style element when it's imported from another css file

Tags: css

I have an issue : 
I'm working on an existing page which uses this calss , **componentContainer** to set different page style.

In order to update the screen content i had to include an existing .css file, so everything works fine but ia have a problem with this file in fact it also implement a class named also **componentContainer**, as follow:

```
#componentContainer {
    background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
}
```

As you can see the page background is grey but i want it white. 
Which is the best way to get rid of this style element background-color: **rgb(242, 242, 242)** without affecting the page content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give:

```
#componentContainer {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

in your external **CSS** file to change the colour.

If it does not work use `!important` *[it will force the style to be over-right by your custom style.]*, you can use this style:

```
#componentContainer {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

I hope the above code will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove style definitions but you can override them. CSS styles are applied in order so if you have another style definition

```
#componentContainer {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

and make sure it shows up in your HTML (either inline, in the same CSS file or in a new CSS file) after the style definition mentioned above then that will be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overwrite that class after including desired css file.

Overwrite in your page style with  important property

```
**strong text**componentContainer {background-color: white !important;}
```